# Run SPFX webpart on Sitepage without deploying it

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have developed an SPFX webpart which overrides the existing classes on SitePage.
I need to run the webpart on sitepage without actually deploying it.

When i gulp serve it open local workbench and my webpart displays there but I want to add it on site page and see if the functionality is working fine before deploying it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following process:

1. Start the local server using `gulp serve --nobrowser`
2. Navigate to the site page you want to test
3. Add `?loadSPFX=true &debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js` to the query string
4. Click the **Load debug scripts** button in the **Allow debug scripts?** dialog to confirm you want to run scripts running locally
5. Add the web part to the page to test

See [Debug SharePoint Framework solutions on modern SharePoint pages | Debug SharePoint Framework web parts on modern SharePoint pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-modern-pages#debug-sharepoint-framework-web-parts-on-modern-sharepoint-pages) for more information.